# Table data not inline with table headers when inputting the table data into a new component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table

So I am trying to create a basic table. I have my table headers on one components, and then my table data in another component. I pass in the data from one component to the other via a ngFor loop as follows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody  *ngFor="let tenancy of (tenancy$ | async)">
  <tenancy-card [tenancy]="tenancy" ></tenancy-card>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And then within the tenancy-card component I have the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let tenants of tenancy.tenants">
  <td>{{tenants.first_name}}</td>
  <td>email</td>
</tr>
```

The problem being that this then displays the data not inline as the image below shows:

[image]

Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: What do you mean by "not inline"? Perhaps you can right-click on it and choose "Inspect Element" and see what HTML is rendered? I'm guessing that Angular puts a `<tenancy-card>` element in the HTML, causing invalid HTML to be produced.

Comment: @HereticMonkey as in the table data i.e email is not lined up with its corresponding header i.e email

Comment: you can add a css width property using the percentage format such as each row element takes a specific width (50% for example), this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Within the `tenancy-card component`, we should have something like this:

```js
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "tr[app-tenancy-card]",
  template: `
      <td>{{tenancy.first_name}}</td>
      <td>email</td>
  `
})
export class TenancyCardComponent {
  @Input() tenancy;
}
```

Then, assume that we have the `tenancy-table component`, we could write like this:

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-tenancy-table",
  template: `
    <table>
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let t of tenancyyy" app-tenancy-card [tenancy]="t"></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  `
})
export class TenancyTableComponent {
  tenancyyy = [
    { first_name: "Krise" },
    { first_name: "James" },
    { first_name: "Krise" }
  ];
}
```

The sample data might look different from your, however, by following this example. Hopefully you can solve your problem.

This is the working project on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xwnz2npop

[image]

Above is the demo pic of the sample project.